# gmail inline images don't show in firefox?

Tags: firefox, gmail

I can drag and drop or copy-paste images into the gmail compose-window in firefox 25.0.1 (win7) and they seem to be sent correctly. But the inline images won't show when looking at the mail in "sent mail" or my own inbox.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks for your suggestions!

Note 1: Inline images copy-pasted or drag'n'dropped to gmail under chrome 31.0.1650.63 (linux) do actually display correctly. In firefox on linux drag and drop seems to work but copy-paste not.

Note 2: I tried already tried (following some suggestions on the web) all of the following withouth effect:

- starting firefox with all addons disabled
- deleting google cookies
- disabling "https-only".

Workaround: In this thread https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/974773 the addon gmail-Handler is suggested as a workaround and it works indeed.

Comment: I just updated to firefox 26.0 and it's still the same.

Comment: Have you tried this in another browser to see if it's a problem with Firefox or with GMail?

Comment: thanks for the hint, ChrisF. It is indeed different in chrome. I updated the question.